# Flutter: how to change state when pressed OnTapped

Tags: android, flutter

i want to change the color and trail icon after i click. the problem is the icon and thrail doesn't change after i click the index. this is my code :

```
Widget _builduserlist(BuildContext context, List<postmodel> model) {
    List<bool> itemTappedState = List.generate(model.length, (index) => false);
  
  return  Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: model.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            
            color: itemTappedState[index]
                ? Colors.blue // Change the color when tapped
                : Colors.green,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('${model[index].id}'),
              subtitle: Text('${model[index].dateofinsp}'),
              leading: const Icon(Icons.edit_road),
              trailing: itemTappedState[index]
                  ? const Icon(Icons.check)
                  : const Icon(Icons.warning), // Change the trailing icon when tapped
              onTap: () {
                print(itemTappedState[index].toString());
                setState(() {
                  itemTappedState[index] = !itemTappedState[index];
                  print(itemTappedState[index].toString());
                });
                
                _showConfirmationDialog(context, model[index]);
                
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

i have print the bool before setState() and in SetState(). it changes in the setState() but
not the index. how do i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `itemTappedState` is declared within your `_builduserlist` method:

```
Widget _builduserlist(BuildContext context, List<postmodel> model) {
    List<bool> itemTappedState = List.generate(model.length, (index) => false);
...
}
```

And the `_builduserlist` method re-runs every `setState`. So `itemTappedState` will be reset to the value you set it every time you update the UI.

To solve the problem, move the `itemTappedState` in the State class:

```
List<bool> itemTappedState = List.generate(model.length, (index) => false);
Widget _builduserlist(BuildContext context, List<postmodel> model) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) works inside the [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) of a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html). So you should make your user list widget like this instead:

```dart
class _UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  const _UserList(this.model);

  final List<postmodel> model;

  @override
  State<_UserList> createState() => _UserListState();
}

class _UserListState extends State<_UserList> {
  List<bool> itemTappedState = List.generate(model.length, (index) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** Put this code at top-level (outside any other class)

Comment: but the widget is in Bloc State, how do i do that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I see this "user list" widget is independent from any external states, so this should be fine

Comment: So the parent widget should take this widget as its child like this: `Container(child: _UserList(model))` instead of this: `Container(child: _builduserlist(context, model))` (I take Container just for example, I don't know the actual parent widget you're using)